# android settings fragment view like a card layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-preferences, android-settings

I have the following Settings fragment which looks like below:

[image: SettingsFragment]

I want to have the Preference categories displayed as separate card layouts like
the following picture: [image: SettingsFragmentWanted - please ignore the inner pictures only the card layout is important]

Please ignore the inner pictures from the latest image, only the layout is important.

I have this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory 
    android:title="Wsdl">

<EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue="@string/ws_url_default"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/services_summary_modify"
    android:key="ws_url"
    android:summary="@string/services_summary"
    android:title="@string/services_url" />
<EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue="@string/recognition_url_default"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/recognition_services_summary_modify"
    android:key="recognition_ws_url"
    android:summary="@string/recognition_services_summary"
    android:title="@string/recognition_services_url" />
```

```
<PreferenceCategory 
    android:title="Xyzmo Significant settings">
<EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="WorkstepController.Process.asmx"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:key="xyzmo_path"            
        android:selectable="true"
        android:title="@string/path" />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="91.234.168.116"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:key="xyzmo_server"
        android:selectable="true"
        android:title="@string/server" />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="57003"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:key="xyzmo_port"
        android:selectable="true"
        android:title="@string/port" />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="http"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:key="xyzmo_protocol"
        android:selectable="true"
        android:title="@string/protocol" />
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory 
    android:title="Application's version">
<Preference
    android:enabled="true"
    android:key="version"
    android:selectable="true"
    android:summary="@string/version_description"
    android:title="@string/version" />
```

and this java code

```
public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
private static final Object KEY_PREF_SYNC = BeanConstants.WS_URL_PARAMETER;
private static final Object KEY_PREF_RECOG = BeanConstants.RECOGNITION_URL_PARAMETER;
private static final String KEY_VERSION = "version";

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    try {
        PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(getActivity().getPackageName(), 0);
        findPreference(KEY_VERSION).setSummary(packageInfo.versionName);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        LogS.e(e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (key.equals(KEY_PREF_SYNC)) {
        // Set summary to be the user-description for the selected value
        BeanConstants.WS_URL = sharedPreferences.getString(key, BeanConstants.WS_URL);
        if (BeanConstants.WS_URL != null && !BeanConstants.WS_URL.endsWith("/")) {
            BeanConstants.WS_URL = BeanConstants.WS_URL + "/";              
        }
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(BeanConstants.WS_URL_PARAMETER, BeanConstants.WS_URL).commit();
        Log.d(PrefsFragment.class.toString(), "Changing WS url to [" + BeanConstants.WS_URL + "]");            

    } 
    if (key.equals(KEY_PREF_RECOG)) {
        // Set summary to be the user-description for the selected value
        BeanConstants.RECOGNITION_WS_URL = sharedPreferences.getString(key, BeanConstants.RECOGNITION_WS_URL);
        if (BeanConstants.RECOGNITION_WS_URL != null && !BeanConstants.RECOGNITION_WS_URL.endsWith("/")) {
            BeanConstants.RECOGNITION_WS_URL = BeanConstants.RECOGNITION_WS_URL + "/";
          }
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(BeanConstants.RECOGNITION_URL_PARAMETER, BeanConstants.RECOGNITION_WS_URL).commit();
        Log.d(PrefsFragment.class.toString(), "Changing RECOGNITION WS url to [" + BeanConstants.RECOGNITION_WS_URL + "]");

    }

    if (key.equals(BeanConstants.XYZMO_PATH_PARAMETER)) {
        // Set summary to be the user-description for the selected value
        BeanConstants.XYZMO_PATH_VALUE = sharedPreferences.getString(key, BeanConstants.XYZMO_PATH_VALUE);
        if (BeanConstants.XYZMO_PATH_VALUE != null) {
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString(BeanConstants.XYZMO_PATH_PARAMETER, BeanConstants.XYZMO_PATH_VALUE).commit();
            Log.d(PrefsFragment.class.toString(), "Changing " + BeanConstants.XYZMO_PATH_PARAMETER + " to [" + BeanConstants.XYZMO_PATH_VALUE + "]");               
          }            
    }

    if (key.equals(BeanConstants.XYZMO_SERVER_PARAMETER)) {
        // Set summary to be the user-description for the selected value
        BeanConstants.XYZMO_SERVER_VALUE = sharedPreferences.getString(key, BeanConstants.XYZMO_SERVER_VALUE);
        if (BeanConstants.XYZMO_SERVER_VALUE != null) {
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString(BeanConstants.XYZMO_SERVER_PARAMETER, BeanConstants.XYZMO_SERVER_VALUE).commit();
            Log.d(PrefsFragment.class.toString(), "Changing " + BeanConstants.XYZMO_SERVER_PARAMETER + " to [" + BeanConstants.XYZMO_SERVER_VALUE + "]");               
          }            
    }

    if (key.equals(BeanConstants.XYZMO_PORT_PARAMETER)) {
        // Set summary to be the user-description for the selected value
        BeanConstants.XYZMO_PORT_VALUE = sharedPreferences.getString(key, BeanConstants.XYZMO_PORT_VALUE);
        if (BeanConstants.XYZMO_PORT_VALUE != null) {
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString(BeanConstants.XYZMO_PORT_PARAMETER, BeanConstants.XYZMO_PORT_VALUE).commit();
            Log.d(PrefsFragment.class.toString(), "Changing " + BeanConstants.XYZMO_PORT_PARAMETER + " to [" + BeanConstants.XYZMO_PORT_VALUE + "]");               
          }            
    }

    if (key.equals(BeanConstants.XYZMO_PROTOCOL_PARAMETER)) {
        // Set summary to be the user-description for the selected value
        BeanConstants.XYZMO_PROTOCOL_VALUE = sharedPreferences.getString(key, BeanConstants.XYZMO_PROTOCOL_VALUE);
        if (BeanConstants.XYZMO_PROTOCOL_VALUE != null) {
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString(BeanConstants.XYZMO_PROTOCOL_PARAMETER, BeanConstants.XYZMO_PROTOCOL_VALUE).commit();
            Log.d(PrefsFragment.class.toString(), "Changing " + BeanConstants.XYZMO_PROTOCOL_PARAMETER + " to [" + BeanConstants.XYZMO_PROTOCOL_VALUE + "]");               
          }            
    }
}
}
```

I need to know how I can update the code in the xml file or in java file to have the SettingsFragment displayed like second picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override onCreateView and use your own custom view. I don't think you have much control over the preferences layout.